# When to use exclamation mark in clojure (or lisp)?

Tags: clojure, naming

#### They say that use exclamation marks when naming impure functions.

But I don't exactly understand the "impure" functions. Are they

- functions change state of their arguments (via reset!, alter, java-object-methods, ...)
- functions occur side-effect (for example, print, spit, ...)
- or both?

Obviously, official clojure apis don't have bang!s on every case above. I wonder when should I put them and need your help to make my code saner.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I would say you don't need to put `!` on every impure function. [Community Clojure Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/clojure-style-guide) recommends:

> The names of functions/macros that are not safe in STM transactions
>   should end with an exclamation mark.

So, basically, end with `!` functions that change state for atoms, metadata, vars, transients, agents and io as well.

Thanks to @noisesmith for update.

Comment: `(->> (ns-publics 'clojure.core) (map (comp name first)) (filter #(re-matches #".*!$" %)))` many of these results have nothing to do with safety in STM transactions.

Comment: @noisesmith They do in the sense that a retried STM transaction containing invocations of those functions may yield different results since they mutate state not under the control of the STM.

Comment: If that is so, I think it is more clear to say that ! is for mutation of state. Not just atoms, but metadata, vars, transients, agents and io as well.

Comment: and I doubt even that list is exhaustive

Comment: I'd say ! is for everything that cannot be safely re-tried.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my article answering your question https://clojure.wladyka.eu/posts/when-use-exclamation-mark/

In simple explanation the rule is like that:

> `(create-user! ...)` has additional effects if you run it more than once with the same input. For example send e-mail each time or create +1 user.

> `(create-user ...)` wouldn’t have additional effects even if you run this many times with the same input.

If it is still not clear think about this:
`(create-user! ...)` vs `(create-user-only-if-not-exist ...)`.