# How do you make a var set!-able in the Leiningen user repl?

Tags: clojure, leiningen, read-eval-print-loop, thread-local

I've got a dynamic var in a namespace defined in a source file, like this:

```
(ns mystuff.log ...)

(def ^:dynamic *logging* #{})
```

I'd like to be able to `set!` this var from the REPL, so that code in that same source file can look at it. In this example, the `mystuff.log/log` macro looks at `*logging*` to decide whether to print a given expression. At the REPL, it would be convenient to `(set! *logging* #{:whatever})`, changing its value multiple times during the session.

How can I get Leiningen's REPL to allow this? By default, `set!`ing such a var produces an IllegalStateException because `set!` can't change the root binding of a var. The var must be thread-local to be changeable by `set!`.

Is there a way to tell Leiningen to wrap its REPL something like this, to create a thread-local binding for a var?

```
(binding [mystuff.log/*logging* mystuff.log/*logging*]
  (the-leiningen-repl ...))
```

The `:init` option of `:repl-options`, briefly explained [here](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj#L344), seems like it offers something close. Apparently, though, the REPL calls `:init`, which would make it too late to establish a thread-local binding for the expressions typed into the REPL.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want [`alter-var-root`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/alter-var-root), not `set!`. With no special set-up or modifications to the REPL, here's what you can do:

```
user> (def logging #{})
#'user/logging

user> (alter-var-root #'logging conj :my-new-logger)
#{:my-new-logger}

user> (alter-var-root #'logging conj :another-new-logger)
#{:my-new-logger :another-new-logger}

user> logging
#{:my-new-logger :another-new-logger}


#{:my-new-logger :another-new-logger}
```

`set!` modifies only a var's current thread binding. `alter-var-root` modifies the var's root binding: the value that's shared across all threads where it's not overridden by a per-thread binding.*

---

*By the way, that's why `alter-var-root` doesn't have an exclamation point. It follows the same convention as other forms that modify root bindings, like `def`.

Comment: So, how can I set up the Leiningen REPL so that the var gets a thread-local binding before the `user=>` prompt appears? In other words, the REPL should run as if wrapped inside a `binding`.

Comment: Let's take one step back and ask what you're trying to do. `set!` is extremely rarely the answer for changing root values. most people want alter-var-root which does not require any of this, and just sets the value in the var.

Comment: I just want to be able to change the value of a custom global variable at will from the REPL, possibly multiple times. (The question gives an example: changing a set of things to log.)

Comment: Ah, it sounds like `alter-var-root` may indeed be what I need. Not what I expected! But indeed something I didn't like about `set!` was that it wouldn't ensure that the value got bound to a set (and actually I've got a little function that incorporates implied items into the set of logging variables), so `alter-var-root` seems much preferable.

Comment: I'm surprised that `alter-var-root` lacks an exclamation point. Do you know why it doesn't have one?

Comment: @BenKovitz The usage of exclamation points in Clojure, even in the core library, is very inconsistent.

Comment: @SamEstep Thanks for that bit of info. Well, that explains why I passed over `alter-var-root` when browsing through the API.

Comment: alter-var-root lacks a ! for the same reason that `def` is not `def!`, which is basically convention and language design. var's are not like the other controlled-mutation types and root bindings are not guaranteed to be thread safe in all contexts like the other controlled-mutation types (which do use the !) NOTE: set! does not work on `var`s it works on thread-locals that are made from vars.

Comment: @ArthurUlfeldt Ahhh, that makes sense. I'm carrying expectations from Scheme into Clojure, beyond where they apply. Thanks! And thanks for the quick response and getting to the bottom of what I was trying to do. I put this to work right away. Would you mind if I edit your answer to make the part about `alter-var-root` more prominent, and to include what I've learned from these comments? I think I see a way to make it speak directly to my state of mind two hours ago (and to anyone else holding the same wrong expectations). :) If you don't like my edit, I won't mind if you roll it back.

Comment: edit away! I basically always appreciate people improving answers. The real target audience here is the people who google in later. (though it's good that you get your stuff working as well)

Comment: Excellent. I just submitted the edit. Do please double-check to be sure I didn't put in any misinformation! :)

Comment: @BenKovitz Arthur provided a reasonable explanation of why `alter-var-root` has no exclamation point, but just to try to help you avoid getting tripped up by this in the future, I'd like to say again that their general usage is inconsistent. A quick look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20606249/5044950) (or a Google search for "clojure exclamation point") should make it clear that there is no agreement on this topic. It's a useful tool in the small (like when distinguishing [transient](http://clojure.org/reference/transients) operations from pure ones), but don't rely on it.

Comment: @SamEstep Good point. I'll leave it to Arthur to adjust my update so it doesn't suggest that the convention is more consistent than it really is. (The footnote in my update certainly overstated it.)